# Given two sorted lists, how to find elements that appear in list1 but not in list2?

Tags: algorithm

I was asked this question in an interview.

For example, if given `list1: 1,1,2,4,5,7` and `list2: 1,3,5,8` we should return a `list3: 2,4,7`.

The problem requires constant space, and we need to reduce the time complexity as much as possible.

Comment: Constant space, are you sure?

Comment: You just walk through the lists comparing elements.  To achieve constant space, you would need to remove elements from the first list that are not in the second.

Comment: what language are you using? this is pretty easy to do in python. Just need to pop elements from list one if it is present in list 2.

Comment: @jeffpc1993 the specifics of "is present in" would matter, complexity-wise.

Comment: would printing out count as returning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just walk through both lists at the same time -- using two "pointers" into them -- comparing the current two elements.

- When the first list's current element is less then the second's, we copy the first list's current element at the result's end and advance the first pointer.
- When the first list's current element is bigger than the second's, we advance the second pointer.
- When they are equal, we advance the first pointer.

Stop when the first pointer reaches the end of list. If the second pointer does this first, also copy all the remaining elements in `list1` at the `result`'s end one-by-one, or -- if these are [singly linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) and shared structure is allowed -- point the result's end pointer at the first pointer's value.

Assuming the `result` is a linked list, or other data structure with *O(1)* `add-at-end` operation, this gives us complexity of *O(n+m)* where *n*, *m* are the two lists' lengths.

This operation is otherwise known as set difference `list1 \ list2` or [relative set complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) of `list2` with respect to `list1`.

The two pointers used constitute the constant auxiliary space used by the algorithm.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you very much.